# What is the process for re-evaluating voting results in light of a compromised voting system?

Tags: united-states, election, voting

If some evidence of tampering with voting systems from yesterday's election was found in the future, what would be the process for re-evaluating the results?

Comment: Do you mean legally?

Comment: Of course.  I don't think there's a precedent in US politics, is there?  Would there simply be a new special election scheduled?

Answer (score 1):

There is no process for re-evaluating voting *results* in the United States other than processing recounts.  [link](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12750/what-are-donald-trumps-legal-options-if-he-loses-the-presidential-election/12751#12751) There is no "remedy" available to any governing body, not Courts, not the Legislatures, not the Executive.  Not that the FBI and others wouldn't investigate crimes, but re-evaluating the actual determination who has been certified President is something not contemplated in our governing framework.

Comment: I am not sure this is right. if issues are found, SCOTUS may very well find something in the wording saying the results are void. Without them LOOKING, hard to predict

Comment: @user4012 - The problem is that the results are only *indirect* to the choice of President.  If a problem comes up between now and when the Electors vote, then the state (at its discretion, and per its relevant laws) can send different Electors.  If they've already voted, then it doesn't any any difference if it turns out there was massive fraud (except to the reputation of the person in office).